# Ping and HTTP Get don't work with Twilio programmable wireless SIM

Tags: twilio, networkmanager

I'm using a Programmable Wireless SIM in Canada. I have a Pi and cellular modem that I know work with another carrier's SIM. When I connect with the other SIM I can run ping and wget (HTTP get on github repo) successfully.

When I use the Twilio SIM (APN is set correctly) the device connects to the network and i get an IP address however my ping and wget do not work. In twilio's portal the SIM shows as being in an active data call.

WHen I run wget with a github url the device resolves github to an IP address but then hangs when trying to do a HTTP request. I'm stuck as to what to try as the DNS works and I didn't think any of the higher level protocols had anything to do with the SIM.

One note is I have enabled international roaming but not national (US) roaming on the SIM card's data plan. And Yes there is money in the account / plan :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague had changed the SIM to a plan that didn't include Data. *facepalm*